# PrestaShop creates #sql_ files in /tmp for no reason

Tags: mysql, mariadb, prestashop, temp-tables

In my prestashop I am facing a strange issue. Prestashop creates temporary tables which are placed in /tmp as this is configured in my.cnf which is OK, but the issue why they are being generated and what can cause. Example of a file:
 mysql:mysql /tmp/#sql_c2d_3.MAD

My server is with centos 7, mariadb 10.3, php 7.1. If anything else is needed, I will be happy to share it.

My server is with centos 7, mariadb 10.3, php 7.1 and I checked https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld-fills-tmp-with-file-tmpsql_26be_0mad/ which says: 
When you run certain ALTER or CREATE commands on an InnoDB table, a temporary table is created in mysql's tmpdir during the operation.The default value in my.cnf is /tmp

I am not sure after that if the issue is caused by the server or by prestashop. I checked if a module can cause this, but I was not able to find anything wrong.

Comment: Let me tell you that I worked with PS since 1.4, I have used shared, vps, dedicated, now cloud hosting and I never had that problem, I think the cause is a configuration in your server or modification in PS, to discard PS just create a fresh install and if problem persist is clear the cause is the server, hope this help!

Comment: Perhaps you are doing a complex `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1):

When you run some ALTER/CREATE commands on an InnoDB table, a temporary table is created in MySQL's temporary folder during the operation (Indeed, the default value in my.cnf is /tmp).

To my knowledge, in PrestaShop 1.7.x, Temporary MySQL tables (e.g. using the keyword `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`) are only used on the **Specials** page (listing currently discounted products).

In this file, product reductions are calculated on the fly via a method called `getRandomSpecial()` from the Product class (file `/classes/Product.php`).

I hope this helps, if not, it would suggest scanning your `/modules/` directory for the keyword `TEMPORARY TABLE` in PHP files.

Comment: Thank you! I found that one of the modules are doing CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE! This should be enough to resolve the issue.